# View to Download FileField From Django

Tags: python, django

I have files which are saved to the MEDIA_ROOT - and I am displaying the file paths as URLs in a table in my UI.  I would like for these files to download when the user clicks the link in the table.  However, when that happens I get an error because I don't have a URL or View defined to handle this I suppose.  Problem is, I'm not really sure where to start - any suggestions.  Below is my model, and the .html which displays the table and the link.

models.py

```
class Orders(models.Model):

...

order_file = models.FileField(upload_to='web_unit', null=True, blank=True)

...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.reference
```

index.html

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="main_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" style="width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      ....
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    {% for orders in orders %}

    <tr>

      <td>
        <!-- Update book buttons -->
      <button type="button" class="update-book btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="color: #FFCF8B; border-color: #FFCF8B; background-color: #FFF;" data-id="{% url 'order_update' orders.pk %}">
        <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
      </button>
      </td>

   ....

      <td><a href="{{ orders.order_file }}">Download</a></td> #this is the link

    </tr>
    {% endfor %}


  </tbody>
</table>
```

When the link in the table is clicked - I'd like for the file to be downloaded - I need help on how to define the URL and the View to make this happen.

This has been marked as a duplicate a few times now - but I don't believe it is. The link that I have been referred to only shows a view.  I don't understand how I am to trigger that view using a url since there will be many download links in the same screen. How does the view know which file link I have clicked on? Wouldn't that need to leverage the URL somehow?

Answer (score 1):

First, don't do `{% for orders in orders %}`; instead do `{% for order in orders %}`

Then this should work (assuming order_file is the field name you didn't show in the model)

```
<td><a href="{{ order.order_file.url }}">Download</a></td>
```

Comment: Ok I did that but I am receiving an error ```The 'order_file' attribute has no file associated with it.``` I don't understand what this means, there is certainly a file loaded here? I can see it in the admin panel.

Comment: I've updated to this: ```<td><a href="{{ order.order_file.url|default_if_none:'#' }}">Download</a></td>``` and I'm no longer receiving that error, but now I'm just receiving a 404 error when I click the Download linke @henrym